# An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred

Tags: vb.net, email

I have made an E-mailer like program.  When I start it, it gives me this Error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Menü (VB Version 1.0).exe

My Code

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Public Class Email
    Dim Tárgy As String = TextBox4.Text
    Dim Üzenet As String = TextBox5.Text
    Dim UserEmail As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim UserPass As String = TextBox2.Text
    Dim ToEmail As String = TextBox3.Text
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim MyMailMessage As New MailMessage()
        Try
            MyMailMessage.From = New MailAddress(UserEmail)
            MyMailMessage.To.Add(ToEmail)
            MyMailMessage.Subject = (Tárgy)
            MyMailMessage.Body = (Üzenet)
            Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
            SMTP.Port = 587
            SMTP.EnableSsl = True
            SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential((UserEmail), (UserPass))
            SMTP.Send(MyMailMessage)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I guess you didn't do the program after all then...

Answer (score 1):

Move the initialization of your strings inside the Click event. You don't need them before and doing it at the global level will cause an exception because the TextBoxes and other controls are not yet initialized

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Tárgy As String = TextBox4.Text
    Dim Üzenet As String = TextBox5.Text
    Dim UserEmail As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim UserPass As String = TextBox2.Text
    Dim ToEmail As String = TextBox3.Text

    Dim MyMailMessage As New MailMessage()
    ....            
    SMTP.Send(MyMailMessage)
End Sub
```

Also, if you don't do anything with the exception then do not use empty trt/catch blocks. If an exception occurs then you can't see the error.